# Overwrite Django permission and modify auth_permission

Tags: django, django-permissions

I want to create the permissions in views dynamically instead of the defaults at models

I create a main class called **CreatorView**

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
class CreatorView(View):
    model = None
    fields = None
    exclude = None
    form = None
    page_title = ''
    
    def create_form(self):
        default =dict()
        if self.fields == None:
            if self.exclude == None:
                default['fields'] = self.fields = self.model._meta.fileds
            else:
                default['exclude'] = self.exclude
        else:
            if self.exclude:
                raise Exception('error')
            default['fields'] = self.fields
             

        return modelform_factory(self.model,**default)
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return render('','base.html')
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
      ... and so on
```

the main urls is:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('%s/%s' % (cls.model._meta.app_label, cls.__name__.lower()), cls.as_view(),
     name='%s/%s' % (cls.model._meta.app_label, cls.__name__.lower())) for cls
in CreatorView.__subclasses__()]
```

if I make inheritance from **CreatorView** then my class should create a page
for example:

```
class Login(CreatorView):
    model = Users
    """ my overwrite methods and actions """

class Configurations(CreatorView):
    model = Configure
    """ my overwrite methods and actions """

class Teachers(CreatorView):
    model = Teachers
    """ my overwrite methods and actions """

class Students(CreatorView):
    model = Students
    """ my overwrite methods and actions """

and so on
```

this code will create to me four pages
I want to create table semi to django content_type model to be like:

| id | app_label | page |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | myapp | login |
| 2 | myapp | configurations |
| 3 | myapp | teachers |
| 4 | myapp | students |

Can I modify **auth_permission** table in Django to make *content_type* foreign key from my content_type?
If I can how to prevent insert default permissions and make my insertion for default permission?

Comment: You can use Decorators to Authenticate your views.

Comment: The decorator can perform permission checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create Permissions manually according to docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/)

```
from myapp.models import BlogPost
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(BlogPost)
permission = Permission.objects.create(
    codename='can_publish',
    name='Can Publish Posts',
    content_type=content_type,
)
```

OR

An enhanced permission library which enables a logic-based permission system to handle complex permissions in Django.
[here](https://pypi.org/project/django-permission/)

Comment: Yes thanks for your, I want  to prevent automatic insertion for default permission at migrate

Comment: Also If I modified auth_permission to make its foreign key from my content_type model can I force problems.